# variables showing as undefined in firebug when they are defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my site http://iadprint.com/products?product=Business%20Card

when i select a value for quantity a price is supposed to show in the pricing div on the top right.
this used to work but for some reason today in firebug under dom i can see that a few variables show undefined. when i do the ajax call  iadprint.com/ajax.php?id=1 the data shows correctly and the variables in the js are all defined. what can be wrong? here are the variables that i am seeing undefined.

```
woCoating_price
woColor_price
woDesign_price
woJob_Name_price
woPDF_Proof_price
woQuantity_price
woRound_Corners_price
woTurnaround_price
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced your `$.get()` call with a full `$.ajax()` call that includes an `error:` callback.

The result is that you're getting a parse error because your JSON response is invalid.

```
"parsererror" "Invalid JSON: {"price":"15.00"}<br/>"
```

You need to get rid of that `<br/>` tag.

If this isn't it, then you'll need to provide specific detail on how to reproduce the problem, and in which part of your code you expect to see a defined value.

---

**EDIT:** Here's the `change` handler I used after removing yours:

```
$("#Quantity").change(function () {
    hash = $("#Quantity").val();
    console.log('hash',hash);

    $.ajax({
        url:"ajax.php",
        data: { id: hash },
        dataType:'json',
        success:function (out,b,c) {
            woQuantity_price = out.price;
            displayPrice();
            console.log(out,woQuantity_price,b,c);
        },
        error:function(a,b,c){
            console.log('error:',a,b,c);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: wow that was the problem. i removed it and it worked. i wonder why i had a br there. thanks alot!

Comment: how did you change the $.get to $.ajax in firebug i dont see the $.get anywhere in there

Comment: Do you mean you don't see the `$.ajax` in there? I didn't change it on the server. In the browser's console, I did `$('#Quantity').unbind('change');` to remove the old handler, then I created a new `change` handler that was the same as your original but used an `$.ajax` call instead.

Comment: did you save the browser and try that or you did it in firebug somehow? im curious so that i can find bugs your method in the future :)

Comment: @SarmenB: You can do it in Firebug. I use Chrome, but same concept. Firebug's console gives you a command line (at the bottom) that you can type into. Just try typing `alert('something');` in the console, and hit Enter. You'll get the alert.